# Measuring response time in open rasta

Tags: c#, openrasta, performance, response-time

What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking about something like:

```
    public void Initialize(IPipeline pipelineRunner)
    {
        pipelineRunner
            .Notify(CaptureRequestStartTime)
            .Before<KnownStages.IBegin>();

        pipelineRunner
            .Notify(LogRequestTimeWithStatsd)
            .After<KnownStages.IEnd>();
    }
```

but a bit of advice from someone who knows the internals might be useful.

Is it possible to add custom http handlers in open rasta?

Comment: Even I would like to know this, I would go with similar way but looking for some better way from @sebastian